# Retrieve bean property value from an object

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons-beanutils

My class has multiple fields with getter and setter

While trying to access the value of a property of a bean i have to check the property name and retrieve the value..

```
if(property is this )
    mybean.getThisProperty()    
else if(property is that )    
    mybean.getThatProperty()
else...
```

How i can retireve without actually checking for the propertyname ..

`BeanUtils.copyProperties` in Spring copies property from one bean to another

Comment: You may want to look at the [Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) type and the [reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you can do something like that using Reflection:

```
for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String name = field.getName();
        Object value;
        try {
            if (name.equals(desiredPropertyName)) {
                value = field.get(object); // Do whatever you want with the
                                            // value
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

In the above code, we are getting  all properties in the "object" eve the private fields without using the getter.
This line gives us access to the private fields:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

This line retrieves the name:

```
String name = field.getName();
```

This line retrieves the value:

```
value = field.get(object);
```

If you really want to use the getter, then that's another subject, where you will have to use reflection to invoke methods.

Answer (score 1):

How about the

PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty

of Apaches commons.beanutils